# Existing xml code to oop?

Tags: c#, xml, oop

I have an existing xml code and i want to convert this to a class using c#? I've already tried it but i got confused. Hope you can lend me a hand. Thanks

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();

XmlElement root = doc1.CreateElement("SqlCommand");
doc1.AppendChild(root);

XmlElement tblElem = doc1.CreateElement("Table");
tblElem.SetAttribute("TableName", ddl2.SelectedItem.Text);
root.AppendChild(tblElem);

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    XmlElement colElem = doc1.CreateElement("Columns");
    if (((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkCol")).Checked)
    {
        colElem.SetAttribute("ColumnName", GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
        tblElem.AppendChild(colElem);
    }
    if (((RadioButton)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("radkey")).Checked)
    {
        colElem.SetAttribute("PKey", ddl2.SelectedItem.Text + "." + GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
        tblElem.AppendChild(colElem);
    }
}
doc1.Save(Server.MapPath(@"XmlFile/") + "config.xml");
```

Comment: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate site for such questions

Comment: `I've already tried it but i got confused` - by what?

Comment: @KonradMorawski already tried the oop structure but was confused on how to create the class out of the above code.

Answer (score 1):

A class should only have one responsibility. Your current code mixes xml processing with updating UI (the GridView).

Creating a class out of it does not by itself make for an OOP architecture in real sense.

Different layers / responsibilities should be separated before you think of refactoring the code into classes. What classes would that be then?

Eg. **(a)** one to represent the data (that comes in your xml and gets displayed in the GridView later on), **(b)** one to extract that data from the upcoming xml and **(c)** another one to fill the GridView with that data.

Only this would make your code more flexible, testable and clearer - the benefits of the object-oriented approach. Creating a class solely for the sake of doing so misses the point completely.

Comment: Thank you Konrad, i am still confuse on how to represent the data on the properties or what methods to be created. Can you lend me a hand on how create the above code to a class?

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is too broad for the format of this forum. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - in particular point 3 (`"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."`). You are not asking specifically about anything in particular, just an overall how-to. This goes beyond the scope of an answer on Stack Overflow. I recommend you read up on OOP. Good luck with the project, anyhow